# cross site collection file property update in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnp, reactjs

is there a way to update SharePoint Library file properties from different site collection? I have file uploaded to https://sharepoint.com/sites/site1 & I need to update the file property from https://sharepoint.com/sites/site2. I looked in PNPjs library but get no success. If anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code based on previous code.

```
protected UploadFile() {
    var files = (document.getElementById('uploadFile') as HTMLInputElement).files;

    var file = files[0];
    if (file != undefined || file != null) {
      let spOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: file
      };

      var url = `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyDoc')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='${file.name}', overwrite=true)`

      this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, spOpts).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        console.log(`Status code: ${response.status}`);
        console.log(`Status text: ${response.statusText}`);
        response.json().then((responseJSON: JSON) => {
          console.log(responseJSON);

          let readOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json"
            }
          }

          this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(responseJSON["@odata.id"] + "/ListItemAllFields", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, readOpts).then((readResponse: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            readResponse.json().then((metadataJSON: JSON) => {
              console.log(metadataJSON);
              var metadataType = metadataJSON["@odata.type"].replace('#', '');

              //SP.Data.MyDocItem metadata
              var metaDataBody: string = JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': {
                  'type': metadataType
                },
                'Title': 'testupdate'
              });
              let updateOpt: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
                headers: {
                  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                  "If-Match": "*",
                  "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                  'odata-version': '3.0'
                },
                body: metaDataBody
              }

              this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(responseJSON["@odata.id"] + "/ListItemAllFields", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, updateOpt).then((reqResponse: any) => {
                console.log(reqResponse.status)
              })
            })
          })

        });
      });

    }
  }
```